# Matrix augmentation understanding problem

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, control-theory, optimal-control

I'm currently implementing a *Model Predicitve Control* (MPC) for my mobile robot and i'm using [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.522.1357&rep=rep1&type=pdf) as a reference. I'm currently having the problem of understanding the augmentation of a matrix mentioned in this paper (it's been a while since I worked with matrices). We have these two matrices

[image]

which should be augmented into these matrices

[image]

The first one is easy, it's just calculating `A` with the corresponding parameter `k` and append them. But for `B` I don't undertstand how this should be done. Here `A` is a 3x3 matrix and B is 3x2 matrix. <strike>First I cannot multiply them because of dimension mismatch and secondly even if B would be a 1x3 matrix</strike> how would I resize `B(k|k)` to fit in there?

Comment: Why are you not able to multiply a 3 by 3 matrix by a 3 by 2 matrix? Take a close look at the order they appear in.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Yes you are right, sorry for that, sometimes after a long day you somehow 'stand on the hose' an don't see obvious things. The result of `A` and `B` is a 3 by 2 Matrix which has the same size like `B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's expand it a little bit.

With a prediction horizon $N_p$ and control horizon $N_c$ (in your case $N_c=N_p=N$), the expanded explanation is as follows

The system dynamics:

\begin{align}
&\boldsymbol x(t+1) = \boldsymbol A \boldsymbol x(t) + \boldsymbol B \boldsymbol u (t) \nonumber \\
&\boldsymbol y(t) =  \boldsymbol C \boldsymbol x(t) \end{align}

The future states:

\begin{align}
&\boldsymbol x(t+1|t)=\boldsymbol A \boldsymbol x(t)+\boldsymbol B \boldsymbol u(t) \label{x-future-calc} \\
&\boldsymbol x(t+2|t)=\boldsymbol A \boldsymbol x(t+1|t)+\boldsymbol B \boldsymbol u(t+1)= \nonumber \\
&~~~~~~~~\boldsymbol A^2 \boldsymbol x(t)+\boldsymbol A\boldsymbol B \boldsymbol u(t) +\boldsymbol B\boldsymbol u(t+1) \nonumber\\
&\dots \nonumber\\
&\boldsymbol x(t+N_p|t)=\boldsymbol A^{N_p} \boldsymbol x(t)+\boldsymbol A^{N_p-1} \boldsymbol B \boldsymbol u(t)+ \nonumber \\
&~~~~~~~~\boldsymbol A^{N_p-2} \boldsymbol B \boldsymbol u(t+1)+\dots+ \nonumber \\
&~~~~~~~~\boldsymbol A^{N_p-N_c} \boldsymbol B \boldsymbol u(t+N_c-1) \nonumber
\end{align}

The future output:

\begin{align}
&\boldsymbol y(t+1|t)= \boldsymbol C\boldsymbol A \boldsymbol x(t)+\boldsymbol C\boldsymbol B \boldsymbol u(t) \label{y-future-calc} \\
&\boldsymbol y(t+2|t)= \boldsymbol C\boldsymbol A \boldsymbol x(t+1|t)+\boldsymbol B \boldsymbol u(t+1)=  \nonumber \\
&~~~~~~~~\boldsymbol C\boldsymbol A^2 \boldsymbol x(t)+\boldsymbol C\boldsymbol A\boldsymbol B \boldsymbol u(t) + \boldsymbol C\boldsymbol B\boldsymbol u(t+1) \nonumber\\
&\dots \nonumber\\
&\boldsymbol y(t+N_p|t)=\boldsymbol C\boldsymbol A^{N_p} \boldsymbol x(t)+\boldsymbol C\boldsymbol A^{N_p-1} \boldsymbol B \boldsymbol u(t)+ \nonumber \\
&~~~~~~~~\boldsymbol C\boldsymbol A^{N_p-2} \boldsymbol B \boldsymbol u(t+1)+\dots+\nonumber \\
&~~~~~~~~\boldsymbol C\boldsymbol A^{N_p-N_c} \boldsymbol B \boldsymbol u(t+N_c-1) \nonumber
\end{align}

Vectors of inputs and outputs:

\begin{align}
\boldsymbol Y=\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol y(t+1|t)\\\boldsymbol y(t+2|t)\\ \vdots \\ \boldsymbol y(t+N_p|t)\\\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{(N_pN_{out})\times 1} ,\quad
\boldsymbol U=\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol u(t) \\ \boldsymbol u(t+1) \\ \vdots \\ \boldsymbol u(t+N_c-1) \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{(N_cN_{in})\times 1}
\end{align}

Future dynamics in a neat form:

\begin{align} 
\boldsymbol Y=\tilde{ \boldsymbol A}\boldsymbol X(t)+\tilde{ \boldsymbol B} \boldsymbol U
\end{align}

where

$$\tilde{\boldsymbol A}=\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol CA \\ \boldsymbol C\boldsymbol A^2 \\ \boldsymbol C\boldsymbol A^3 \\ \vdots \\ \boldsymbol C\boldsymbol A^{N_p}\end{bmatrix}, \quad \tilde{ \boldsymbol B}=\begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol C\boldsymbol B & \boldsymbol 0 & \dots & \boldsymbol 0 \\
\boldsymbol C\boldsymbol A\boldsymbol B & \boldsymbol C\boldsymbol B & \dots & \boldsymbol 0 \\
\boldsymbol C\boldsymbol A^2\boldsymbol B & \boldsymbol C\boldsymbol A\boldsymbol B & \dots & \boldsymbol 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\boldsymbol C\boldsymbol A^{N_p-1}\boldsymbol B & \boldsymbol C\boldsymbol A^{N_p-2}\boldsymbol B & \dots & \boldsymbol C\boldsymbol A^{N_p-N_c}\boldsymbol B
\end{bmatrix}$$

---

Here is the point: *You should not expect the matrix blocks to be square.*

BTW, in your case, $\boldsymbol C=\boldsymbol I$.

**Reference:** Mohammadi, Arash, et al. "Optimizing Model Predictive Control horizons using Genetic Algorithm for Motion Cueing Algorithm." Expert Systems with Applications 92 (2018): 73-81. [[sciencedirect]](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0957417417306000) [[researchgate]](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/319575752_Optimizing_Model_Predictive_Control_Horizons_using_Genetic_Algorithm_for_Motion_Cueing_Algorithm)